# Google Cast Receiver Error "NETWORK/3110"

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

When trying to load an .m3u8 file, my receiver's log are showing `[cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/3110` and the video fails to play.

The response headers according to the Chrome inspector:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
CF-RAY:3b8ada35b5de6db4-SJC
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 04 Nov 2017 22:01:32 GMT
Server:cloudflare-nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Robots-Tag:noindex`

...the Response tab of the Chrome Inspector is empty for the .m3u8 file request, so I am assuming that the response was discarded by the browser. Does the cast receiver have additional requirement to enable CORS, beyond the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? Could it be an issue with the response body as opposed to the headers?

Comment: You have to ensure that both the playlist and the segments support CORS.

Comment: You are right, the issue wasn't with the original m3u8 (let's call it the `master playlist`) but with the m3u8 referenced from the master (`segment playlist`). It turns out that the server was responding to the receiver's request for the `segment playlist` with an HTTP 520 error (and the 520 error didn't have CORS headers)